# Why do I need div table in my layout? - yii

Tags: php, html, yii

I'm running into a strange scenario involving a widget and the lay-out. I've created a layout that overrides the original column 2 lay-out. It calls a widget in the file and in that widget display a table on the side-bar of some information that I would like to show the user. The layout sidetable.php looks like this

```
    <?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/main'); ?>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
            <?php 
        $this->widget('ListSummaryWidget', array('totaldue'=>$totaldue)); 
        ?>
    <table class="table">

  </table>


        </div><!-- sidebar span3 -->
        <div class="span9">
        <div class="main">
            <?php echo $content; ?>
        </div><!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>

    <?php $this->endContent();  ?>
```

Now all this works  - displaying a datatable on the left hand column of the screen. However, something strange happens. Whenever I git rid of

```
<table class="table">

  </table>
```

The whole view breaks - showing a ridiculous structure/layout that doesn't look much at all like the original. This is confusing/intriguing. In my widget I declare *the exact same table* and yet it does not seem to matter that I declare this table. Here is the code for my widget's view

```
<table class="table list_summary table-bordered">
    <form action="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('recipient/processpayment', array('id'=>$id)) ?>" method="post" >
        <tr class="primary"><td> <h4>List Summary </h4> </td></tr>
        <tr ><td>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $numpeople; ?> Recipient(s)
        </td></tr>

        <tr ><td>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;Total Due: &nbsp;<?php echo $totaldue ?> Rwf
        </td></tr>

       <tr> <td>  

            <h4> Mobile Money Accounts: </h4> 
            <?php 
            /*
                foreach($accounts as $account)
                {
                    echo $account->name; ?>:&nbsp; <?php echo $account->balance; ?> Rwf<br> <?php  
                } 
                */      
            ?>  

        </td> </tr>

        <tr> <td> 
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary " type="submit">Pay Now</button>  </td> </tr> 
        </td></tr>
    </form>
```

Could anyone explain why this is happening? Though it's not the worst thing in the world - I'm really intrigued as to why I'm required to have some html when I have the same html in the widget's view.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

I didn't end the table in my widget. I should have added at the end

```
</table>
```

Comment: if you found the answer by yourself please accept it a your solution